# How to change window style/theme in c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, styles, window, themes

I need an approach how to customize the window style like Steam or Spotify. I don't want to have the boring Windows (or any other OS) look.
Can that be done with Qt or the WinApi? Do I need DirectX or OpenGL for doing that?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with the WinAPI. The primary message you care about is `WM_NCPAINT`. That's what's sent when the non-client areas of a window (e.g., the frame and title bar) need to be painted.

Note that by default, rendering of the non-client areas is handled by the desktop window manager (DWM). If you're going to handle your own drawing, you usually want to explicitly enable/disable that with `DwmSetWindowAttribute`. Otherwise, you can get strange symptoms (e.g., if try to switch back to "stock" frames and such, it may not "notice" and start drawing your frame again).

Microsoft has an [article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195.aspx) with more details on doing this in conjunction with DWM.