# How can I modify the sdl2 window frame?

Tags: c++, windows, sdl-2

I am using sdl2 in c++, and want to modify the window frame in my application. Can this be achieved and implemented?

I had a look here: [How to change window style/theme in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263371/how-to-change-window-style-theme-in-c) - but I'm not sure how it can mix in.

```
#include "SDL.h"

SDL_Window *window;

void main()
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("TEST", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Delay(3000);
}
```

I would like to build in a file menu and edit menu to the actual frame on the header and possibly change the color or make tabs in the frame as with google chrome.

Comment: If you are expecting that smb provides your source code of the whole application, you are wrong here. Ask more specific question. You want menu? Do it. You want to change color? Do it. Provide your code. Show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

One of SDL's main goals is to abstract window creation, so you don't have to deal with each OS's little tweaks. Said that, I don't think there is a portable, clean way to that using SDL.

What I would do is to go down the level of abstraction: Use WinAPI or MFC or one of Microsoft abstractions over the WinAPI to actually customize the window and then use DirectX or OpenGL to do all graphics. You can still use SDL for audio, input, etc. though.